# Selecting MIN for a day from MIN(s) of hours without temp table?

Tags: mysql, max, min, temp-tables

I have a query that selects MIN values for each hour:

```
SELECT MIN(price), HOUR(timestamp), DATE(timestamp) 
FROM `scan` 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp)
```

Now I need to select MIN and MAX for each MIN(price) for each day. It should be easy using temp table but I'm not sure if performance wise it'll be OK. What are the other ways to make it?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you wanted to find the MIN and MAX hours of these prices (the question wasn't very clear about this).

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(ta.timestamp), ta.price, MIN(HOUR(ta.timestamp)), MAX(HOUR(ta.timestamp))
FROM `scan` ta
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(price) AS minprice, DATE(timestamp) AS day
    FROM `scan` 
    GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
) tb 
ON (tb.minprice = ta.price AND tb.day = DATE(ta.timestamp))
GROUP BY DATE(ta.timestamp), ta.price
```

The subquery fetches the MIN price per day, and the main query is then limited to the records matching day and minprice.

Comment: It is worth noting, since performance was mentioned as a concern, that internally MySQL will probably be creating a temporary table. This is unavoidable without explicitly creating and loading a temp table in preceding queries. Creating temp tables explicitly allows for the inclusion of helpful indexes, the internal versions will not have such optimizations. ...but going the explicit route before you expect there to be a performance issue could be considered premature optimization.